# Regex for replacing all characters excepting last and first non space ones

Tags: regex, replace, hana

I have emails stored in SAP Hana table column of char datatype. I need to replace all letters and digits with '*' char excepting first and last non-whitespace chars. I wrote the regex like this: regex_replace('abcd@efg.hij', '(?!^)[A-Za-z0-9](?!$)', '*')
It works fine and I get masked email 'a***@***.**j'.
But it goes wrong when there are some white spaces at the start and/or the end of the email. For example, if the email string is ' abcd@efg.hij ' the result would be 
' ****@***.**** ' while I need ' a***@***.**j '
Unfortunately, I cannot trim email before regexing.

Comment: Try `(?<!^\s*)[A-Za-z0-9](?!\s*$)`

Comment: Tried and got an invalid syntax error. I tried (?!^\s*)[A-Za-z0-9](?!\s*$) and it leads to almost correct result  ****@***.***j

Comment: This approach cannot be used if variable width lookbehind is not supported. What is the regex flavor? Does `\G.` pattern work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denis, I tried following in a SELECT statement with Replace_Regexp function

```
select
REPLACE_REGEXPR('(?!^)[\sA-Za-z0-9](?!$)' IN trim('    abcd@efg.hij   ') WITH '*')
from dummy;
```

It removes the leading and trailing spaces and returns "a***@***.**j"

Comment: That's it! I forget that Hana provides trim function. Great, thanks for your advice, Eralper.